# C++ save reference of object in variable

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++ and want to accomplish something like this but it doesn't work as I expect it to.

```
Object& object = Object();
```

I want to save the reference the the object I created in the variable `object`.
How do I do this? Thanks.

Edit:
I'm trying to pass the reference to the object to the constructor of another object. It has to be the reference (or pointer?) because it's code for an arduino that doesn't have much memory.

Comment: You can't do that but maybe if you specify what you really need people might be able to suggest alternatives.

Comment: You could do `Object o;`, then `Object& o_ref = o;`

Comment: You need `Object&& object = Object();` When in doubt, double the punctuator..

Comment: Why not just `Object object;`? In what way is that not sufficient but your proposed code would be?

Comment: http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/73-passing-arguments-by-reference/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two legal ways to store the variable by reference:

```
// o1 is const
const Object& o1 = Object();

// o2 is mutable
Object&& o2 = Object();
```

There is a special rule in c++ that keeps the Object alive for as long as the reference is in scope.

What you might want to do is merely store the object:

```
Object o = Object();
```

Comment: Can I store the object in a variable and pass it to every constructor i need to pass it to like so: Object &o ?

Comment: @Jochim If the constructors you're passing it to take `const Object&` or `Object&` arguments then you can simply pass the `Object` instance to it.

Comment: @Jochim When a function expects a (non-const)reference to an object, that means it may modify it's value. But that doesn't mean you can't pass object instance to an Object& argument.

Comment: @Jochim In that case, you can just instantiate using `Object o;` and then all of your parameter lists should say `Object &o`. For example, a method declared as `void func(Object &o)` would be called with `func(o);` and it would be pass-by-reference.